# mysql - add column with precalculated values using closest representation from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that I have a following table

```
id  value1  value2  value1_plus_value2
0   1.0     2.2     null
1   2.1     3.5     null
2   5.2     2.9     null
3   1.5     1.4     null
```

and table for mapping values

```
value   name
2.0     "almost three"
3.0     "about three"
3.5     "three and half"
5.5     "five point five"
6.0     "a lot more than five"
```

And resulting table should look something like

```
id  value1  value2  value1_plus_value2
0   1.0     2.2     "about three"
1   2.1     3.5     "five point five"
2   5.2     2.9     "a lot more than five"
3   1.5     1.4     "about three"
```

How should this be done? It's rather simple to do row by row using some external script and using loop, but there's quite likely some sql way to do this also;

With following I can do this for one row:

```
select id, value1, value2, name, abs(value1+value2-value) as distance
from value, mapping
where id=1
group by distance
limit 1;
```

Added sqlfiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1ac73/1

I want to do this for all the rows. And add found closest names to value table.

So metacode for table I would like to get would be something like

```
select outerquery.value1, outerquery.value2, name as value1_plus_value2
from value as outerquery,
(
select id, value1, value2, name, abs(value1+value2-value) as distance
from value, mapping
where id = outerquery.id
group by distance
limit 1
) as subquery;
```

But apparently I can't pass data from outerquery to subquery. But I'm sure that I'm just thinking this wrong.

Comment: what is the join condition/

Comment: @SashiKant added this information to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amended to suit refined criteria...

```
SELECT value.*,mapping.* 
  FROM value
  JOIN mapping
  JOIN
     ( SELECT value.id
            , MIN(ABS((value.value1+value.value2)-mapping.value))min_abs 
         FROM value
         JOIN mapping
        GROUP 
           BY id
     ) x
    ON x.id = value.id
   AND x.min_abs = ABS((value.value1+value.value2)-mapping.value)
 ORDER
    BY id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1ac73/6

Comment: I added more info to question and example for id=1 what I want to do for all the rows

Comment: I simplified example a bit http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aee75/5
I want to join mapping table with value table where ABS(value.value-mapping.value) is the smallest possible number (can be any possible double value)